# Trouble splitting an array of integers using a delimiter

Tags: java, arrays, integer

I'm writing a method which gets as an input an array of integers and an integer which is the delimiter. It splits the array according to the delimiter and it returns a 2D array so that each line contains the numbers in the array up until the delimiter (not including the delimiter).

Examples:

Input :

```
{1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1}, 3
```

Output:

```
[1, 2]
[1, 2]
[1, 1, 2, 2]
[1]
```

Input: `{3, 1, 3, 3}, 3`

Output: `[1]`

but instead when I run my code I don't get anything in return, I ran it in debug mode and I got that my result was `[null, null, [1, 2]]`

What should I fix in my code?

```
public static int[][] splitArrayByNum(int[] input, int number) {
    if (input[0] == number)
        for (int i = 0; i < input.length - 1; i++) {
            input[i] = input[i + 1];
        }

    if ((input[(input.length) - 1]) == number)
        for (int i = (input.length) - 1; i < input.length - 1; i++) {
            input[i] = input[i + 1];
        }

    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++)
        if (input[i] == number) {
            count++;
        }

    int[][] result = new int[count][];
    int firstindex = 0;
    int lastindex = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < input.length; j++) {

        if (input[j] == number) {
            result[j] = Arrays.copyOfRange(input, firstindex, lastindex);
            firstindex = lastindex = j;
        }
        lastindex++;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: i don't quite understand what your code is supposed to do....

Comment: I suggest you sit down and think through the problem logically. The above is dramatically more complicated than you need. Just have the method start at the beginning, remember where it started, scan the array for the delimiter, when it finds it grab everything between where it started and where it is, update where it started, and go again. When it gets to the end, grab anything left.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I've had a crack at it, can someone else come up with something a bit more elegant cus this doesn't feel like it's as simple as it could be?

```
public static int[][] arraySplitByDelimiter(int[] inputArray, int delimiter) {

           //Make an array to hold our results, ideally it would be nice to use an ArrayList
        //so that it can expand dynamically but instead we can also make one that we know will be big enough
        //if every other int is a delimiter then we can end up with a result array of inputArray.length / 2
        int[][] temporaryResultArray = new int[inputArray.length / 2][];
        int numberOfResultArrays = 0;

        int lastDelimterPosition = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < inputArray.length; i++) {
            //If we find a delimeter copy the chunk of the input array to a new array in the temporaryResultArray
            if (inputArray[i] == delimiter) {
                temporaryResultArray[numberOfResultArrays++] = Arrays.copyOfRange(inputArray, lastDelimterPosition, i);
                lastDelimterPosition = i + 1;
            } else if (i == (inputArray.length - 1)) {
                //If we're at the end of the array then we should copy the last chunk to new array
                temporaryResultArray[numberOfResultArrays++] = Arrays.copyOfRange(inputArray, lastDelimterPosition, inputArray.length);
            }
        }

        int[][] finalResultArray = new int[numberOfResultArrays][];
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfResultArrays; i++) {
            finalResultArray[i] = temporaryResultArray[i];
        }

        return finalResultArray;

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Just to illustrate flow logic:

```
int[][] result = new int[][];
int resultIndex = 0;

int[] chunk = new int[];
int chunkIndex = 0;

for (int i=0; i<input.length; i++) {
   if (input[i] != number) {
      chunk[chunkIndex++] = input[i];
   }
   else {
      if (chunk.length > 0) {
         result[resultIndex++] = chunk;
         chunk = new int[];
         chunkIndex = 0;
      }
   }
}
if (chunk.length > 0) {
   result[resultIndex] = chunk;
}
```